# Create different decorated object in case of input

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator

Assume that I used decorated design pattern for making a pizza. There are 3 type of ingredients that user can add his pizza. Mozarella, souce and vegetables. I prepared these classes and set the cost. 

 This is main code

```
public class PizzaFactory {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pizza p = new TomatoSauce(new Mozarella(new PlainPizza())); 
        System.out.println(p.getIngredients());
    }
}
```

This is interface

```
public interface Pizza {
    public String getIngredients();
    public int getCost();
}
```

This is base pizza

```
public class PlainPizza implements Pizza{
    @Override
    public String getIngredients() {
        return "Pizza ";
    }
    @Override
    public int getCost() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

This is decorator class

```
abstract class IngredientDecorator implements Pizza{
    protected Pizza tempPizza;

    public IngredientDecorator(Pizza newPizza) {
        this.tempPizza = newPizza;
    }
    public String getIngredients() {
        return tempPizza.getIngredients();
    }
    public int getCost() {
        return tempPizza.getCost();
    }
}
```

One of ingredient class is

```
public class Mozarella extends IngredientDecorator{
    public Mozarella(Pizza newPizza) {
        super(newPizza);
    }

    public String getIngredients() {
        return tempPizza.getIngredients() + " Mozarella";
    }

    public int getCost() {
        return tempPizza.getCost() + 1;
    }
}
```

Others are look like them. 

 Now, I want to take input from user to which ingradient they want. In order to input I will create pizza. They may want just plain pizza. But since, I create my pizza -> Pizza p = new TomatoSauce(new Mozarella(new PlainPizza())); like this. How can I create pizza dinamic? Do I have to check each condition with if-else or switch-case?

Comment: Why are ingredients objects rather than attributes? Your problem would be greatly simplified (to the point of elimination) if you could figure that out.

Comment: Yes, for this sample you are right but think about another way. How could I solve this problem with using decorator pattern.